# Error using criteriaBuilder.max() for LocalDate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteriaquery, criteriabuilder

I am trying to get max date using criteria builder in a subquery.
But I am getting this error

> ```
> Required type: Expression <LocalDate>
> Provided: Expression <Number>
> ```

This is my code:

```java
Subquery<LocalDate> subRoot = criteriaQuery.subquery(LocalDate.class);
subRoot.select(criteriaBuilder.max(root.get("date")));
```

I am trying to get max date from sub query which is required in my parent query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `max` you have to use `greatest` for dates. `Max` is for Numeric types. refer below piece of code for reference

```
EntityManger em;      //to be injected or constructed

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Exam> cq = cb.createQuery(Exam.class);
Subquery<Date> sq = cq.subquery(Date.class);
Root<Exam> s1 = cq.from(Exam.class);
Root<Exam> s2 = sq.from(Exam.class);
sq.select(cb.greatest(s2.get(Exam.end)));
List<Exam> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: Still not wokring now I am getting this error

java: method greatest in interface javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cannot be applied to given types;
  required: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<X>
  found: javax.persistence.criteria.Path<java.lang.Object>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: java.lang.Object
    upper bound(s): java.lang.Comparable<? super java.lang.Object>,java.lang.Object

Comment: I think it seems your date field is has data type other then Timestamp.

Comment: Solved it had to as() sq.select(cb.greatest(s2.get(Exam.end)).as(LocalDate.class)). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
sq.select(cb.max(s2.get(Exam.end)).as(LocalDate.class)));
```